# Can I use 2 routers as one wireless range extender

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, wireless-extender

Ok, so, I have an old router, and I want to use it as a Wi-Fi range extender. I know that many of you will say: "It's easy, just connect them with a cable". That's the problem, I can't connect them as a cable. I want the extender to connect to the main router wirelessly, and I also want to connect to the extender wirelessly. Problem is, my router doesn't support that feature. But, I have 2 old routers, not just one, and I was thinking, can I have the first old router connect wirelessly to the main router, share its connection with the second old router via a cable, and then I can connect to the second old router? Sorry if my question is hard to understand, I'm new to this networking stuff.

Comment: Yes, that should be possible.

Comment: It's possible, but the WiFi networks won't be set up the way one would likely think.  **FYI:** it would only be recommended to use an older router if it's supported by opensource firmware, such as [OpenWrt](https://openwrt.org/toh/start), else it's a security risk since the OEM firmware will lack security patches, such as a vital patch for [KRACK](https://www.pcworld.com/article/3233308/krack-wi-fi-security-flaw-faq-tips.html) _(OEM's only support consumer routers for a year, two at most, before considering them EoL [End of Life] and consumers are lucky if they get even one firmware update)_

Comment: I agree with JW0914, look into openwrt / dd-wrt. If your router supports it you can do all of this. Both have been patched for the krack attack.

Comment: If you want those routers to appear as transparent as possible, in bridge mode rather than router mode, they need to be compatible between themselves (usually same brand or wireless card chipset manufacturer) for WDS mode or 4 addresses mode. Else one of them has to route.